# Responsive Datatable with Bootstrap Export option

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Can anyone help in providing code for responsive datatable with export option, which enables to export data from the table.

Comment: What do you mean about "export option to the data table"?

Comment: @Manh Le: An option to export the contents from table to other formats like pdf,txt etc.. Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4r6g4cfu/90/ but this is not responsive

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may help you

```
<script src="js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
```

`var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            lengthChange: false,
            buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis' ]
        });
        table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );`

**EDIT:**

You will find the details on plugin download link on.
https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: Thanx for the reply.. but where can I get these files for                   `<script src="js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/datatables/jszip.min.js"></script>`....